# Protractor : Remove special characters from String

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm writing protractor tests for my angular application. 
Here is one of my test case. 
I want to compare a span value before and after a button click.

```
it('Compare the dollar values', function () {
            var a = mypage.a.getText();
            mypage.clickBtnUS();
            expect(toNumber(mypage.a.getText())).toEqual(a * 
              mypage.fxRate.getText());
    });
```

*mypage.a* is a span which display dollar amount in format - ***$ 643,584***. I wants to ***remove the special characters such as $ and , from this string before numeric conversion***. Without removing $ and , will result in producing NaN after numeric conversion.
How can I do that.

Any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use regex via `string.replace` : `mypage.a.getText().replace(/\$|,/g, '')`

Comment: Thanks. It helped. As getText() method is returning a promise, I couldn't directly call replace function on the promise. But I used the regexp in nested then . It worked

Comment: you can also use async/await

Answer (score 1):

If you use Node 7 or higher, you can use JavaScript native `Promise.all` API to avoid nested `then`.

```
it('Compare the dollar values', function () {
    Promise.all([
        mypage.a.getText(),
        mypage.clickBtnUS(),
        mypage.a.getText(),
        mypage.fxRate.getText()
    ]).then(function(data){
        var beforeVal = data[0];
        var afterVal = data[2];
        var fRate = data[3];

        return expect(toNumber(afterVal)).toEqual(beforeVal * fRate);
    });
});
```

Comment: It was a good suggestion. Thanks :) . I had to replace the special characters from the data before conversion and comparison.

Answer (score 0):

So, the Answer is

```
 Promise.all([
                    mypage.a.getText(),
                    mypage.fxRate.getText(),
                    mypage.clickBtnUS(),
                    mypage.a.getText(),
                ]).then(function(data){
                    var beforeVal = data[0];
                    var afterVal = data[3];
                    var fRate = data[1];
                    expect(toNumber(afterVal)).toEqual(toNumber(beforeVal) * 
                 toNumber(fRate));
                });
```

I used the replace function inside the toNumber function

```
function toNumber(promiseOrValue) {
        // if it is not a promise, then convert a value
        if (!protractor.promise.isPromise(promiseOrValue)) {
            return parseFloat(promiseOrValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
        }
        // if promise - convert result to number
        return promiseOrValue.then(function (stringNumber) {
            return parseFloat(stringNumber.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
        });
    }
```

Comment: new node 7 code using then

element(by.tagName("td:nth-child(3)"))
                                .getText()
                                .then(function(text) {
                                  text.replace(/\$|,/g, '')
                                });